# Travis CI fails build on cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, travis-ci

this is my first time trying to setup Travis CI with my iOS project. I have this in my .travis.yml file:

```
language: objective-c
script:
    - xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphonesimulator -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

When travis runs it starts compiling but runs into issues with the cocoapods, e.g.:

```
/Users/travis/build/MyApp/ios-app/Pods/Alamofire/Source/AFError.swift:265:38: error: 'case' labels with multiple patterns cannot declare variables
        case .jsonEncodingFailed(let error), .propertyListEncodingFailed(let error):
                                     ^
/Users/travis/build/MyApp/ios-app/Pods/Alamofire/Source/AFError.swift:276:73: error: definition conflicts with previous value
        case .bodyPartURLInvalid(let url), .bodyPartFilenameInvalid(let url), .bodyPartFileNotReachable(let url),
                                                                        ^
/Users/travis/build/MyApp/ios-app/Pods/Alamofire/Source/AFError.swift:276:38: note: previous definition of 'url' is here
        case .bodyPartURLInvalid(let url), .bodyPartFilenameInvalid(let url), .bodyPartFileNotReachable(let url),
```

There are many, many errors displayed that I don't get if I compile locally in Xcode. These all seem to be related to Alamofire too. I made sure that my scheme is set to `share` and also added all the pod target to that scheme. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to specify explicitly the `osx_image` that you want to use, otherwise your project is going to be built with an unspecified version of Xcode (and Swift) that is potentially going to be incompatible with your project.